# CakePhp find all is not working along with condition and recursive

Tags: php, cakephp, recursion

I have an application with two controllers

- Tasks
- Users

I need all user's task which is pending I have a field in task table which is **Status** field it is 1 when task is pending

I tried this in user controller action

```
$users= $this->User->find("all", array('recursive' => 1,'conditions' => array('Task.status' => 1)));
```

the recursive behaviour not working in this case it says unknown column  **Task.status**

When i use this it work fine but give all users's task even they have status 0 or 1

```
$users= $this->User->find("all", array('recursive' => 1));
```

Comment: Did you use following? 

`$this->User->recursise = 1;

$users= $this->User->find("all",'conditions' => array('Task.status' => 1)));`

Comment: yes i did but not working

Comment: `Not working` means ?

Comment: still gives the error of unknown column Task.status

Comment: any way thanks for the help I sort out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem 
I use contain

```
$this->User->contain('Task.status = "1"'); 
   $users= $this->User->find("all", array('recursive' => 1));
```

Comment: I think you should use  

`$users= $this->User->find("all", array('recursive' => 1,'conditions' => array('Task.status' =>"1")));`   .Please try it.